# Linking to a html page in a new window from a button click

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, button, window, spring-tool-suite

I am working in Bootstrap with Spring Tool Suite.  I have a html page I made (reprint-emblems-reports.html) and I want this page to show after a button click of a Go button.  I am working through a localhost.  The site is not live.  I am new to html.

Here is the code for the Go button.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-aramark-primary">Go</button>
```

The Go button is within reprint-emblems.html.

reprint-emblems-reports.html is within the same folder (reprint-emblems)

I want the click of the Go button to bring up a new tab and shows the reprint-emblems-reports.html page.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the "onclick" attribute on your button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-aramark-primary" onclick="window.open('/your-path')">Go</button>
```

window.open() can open a new tab or new window (depends of your browser configuration)

Comment: perfect.  Exactly what I needed.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='/your path here'" type="button" class="btn btn-aramark-primary">Go</button>
```

Comment: great.  This makes the html page pop up.  Now I just need it to show in a new window not the current window.  How would I do that?

Comment: Do this instead `window.open('www.yourdomain.com','_blank');`

Comment: Got it.  Thank you for your help